# number of vertices in a solid

Tags: geometry, self-learning

Determine the number of vertices in a solid made up of $x$ triangles, $y$ squares and $z$ pentagons.

Without using the Euler's formula $v-e+f=2$ and without counting up all vertices by hand I am not sure how to conclude the number of vertices. I am trying to find some relationship based only on the given polygons, something like: For the number of edges I can use $$e=\frac{3x+4y+5z}{2}$$ as every edge is shared by two faces.

Comment: Why can't you use Euler's formula? You just wrote down the number of edges and of course the number of faces is $x + y + z$, so...

Comment: Correct, but I would like to know how to get to the number of vertices when I don't know the total number of faces. The only thing I can think of is $e=\frac{Vc}{2}$ where $c$ is the number of edges coming out of one vertex.

Comment: What do you mean? I don' think that you can figure out the number of vertices of a polyhedron knowing only the number of edges, unless there is quite some regularity involved. Also, the formula you mention works only when the number of edges meeting at a vertex is constant throughout the polyhedron, which need not be the case. For example, think of the [Disdyakis triacontahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disdyakis_triacontahedron) (whose faces are all triangles, by the way).

Comment: If you know only the number of edges about all you can say is $\frac{2}{5}e \le f \le \frac{2}{3}e$. If the solid is not _simple_, and is topologically equivalent to, say, a torus, then even Euler's formula does not hold in the stated form. So, be clear what the constraints are.